# Closing a form wrapped inside a modal in react Js

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-props, edit, react-state

I have a CForm which is a common form file I'm defining to prevent code redundancy and to make it reusable but I'm facing a problem in showing and closing the modal component which is the parent element of the CForm. In the modal component, I define an interface ModalProps like so:

```
interface ModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }
```

and here's the modal component which is a common component like CForm:

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ModalContent, ModalWrapper } from "./modal.styles";
const Modal:React.FC<ModalProps> = ({isOpen,children,onClose}) => {
    const [modalOpen,setModalOpen]=useState(isOpen)
    useEffect(() => {
      setModalOpen(isOpen);
    }, [isOpen]);
  return <>
  {
modalOpen &&(
    <ModalWrapper>
        <ModalContent>{children}</ModalContent>
    </ModalWrapper>
)
  }
  </>;
};
export default Modal;
```

So only when modalOpen is true the modalWrapper and its children show up, In the CForm I have in the props interface and optional isOpen is declared like so:

```
isOpen?:boolean
```

and I define these 3 lines:

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(isOpen || false);
  const handleOpenModal = () => setIsModalOpen(true);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setIsModalOpen(false);
```

where they are used inside these tags:

```
 <Btn backgroundColor="#16C199" onClick={handleOpenModal}>
        Add
      </Btn>
      <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={handleCloseModal}> <Btn
                  backgroundColor="#FF3737"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={handleCloseModal}
                >
```

In my case, I want to open the CForm when I hit edit, so trying to clarify the workflow: the button edit is defined inside a table component like so:

```
<tbody>
        {items && 
          items.map((item: any) => (
            <tr key={item._id}>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <td key={`${item.id}-${column.dataKey}`}>{item[column.dataKey]}</td>
              ))}
              { (
                  <td>
                    <Button backgroundColor='red' onClick={() => onEdit(item._id)}>Edit</Button>
                    <Button backgroundColor='#5832EB' onClick={() => onDelete(item._id)}>Delete</Button>
                  </td>
                )}
            </tr>
              ))}
      </tbody>
```

and I pass the onEdit as a prop by the header of the component:

```
const Table: React.FC<TableProps> = ({ query, columns , dataKey,onDelete,onEdit})
```

inside my customersPresentation, I return those tags:

```
<Container>
    <CForm fields={fields} onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
      <Table  columns={columns} query={GET_CUSTOMERS} dataKey="getCustomers" onEdit={onEdit} onDelete={onDelete}/>
  </Container>
```

you see I'm still passing and onEdit prop by this component header:

```
export const CustomersPresentation:React.FC<CustomerProps> = ({onSubmit,onEdit,onDelete})
```

Finaly, inside the customersContainer, I render the customersPresentation like so:

```
 return <>
  <CustomersPresentation 
       onSubmit={handleSubmitCustomers}
       onDelete={handleDelete} 
       onEdit={handleEdit}
       />
  </>;
```

and inside the handleEdit, I want to open the modal and the CForm. What are the steps to do so to resume this image describes the folder structure of my project folder structure:

> [image: folder structure]

I tried passing down the props back to the CForm, but I didn't suceed. I'm expecting to show the modal as a first step of the handleEdit defined inside the customersContainer.